# Delete a sound in Apple Clips

Tags: music, ios, iphone, clips.app

I just downloaded  Clips, and I discovered that I could add some music in the background that you can download: 
[image: Clips]
But I would like to know if there is a way of deleting these background music without deleting the app.
P.S. : I already tried to swipe to see if there is the delete button, and there isn't .